# Why isn't Newton's Method returning all possible roots in my domain?

Tags: python, numpy

When I run the following code on `sin(x)`:

```
import numpy as np

def newton(z0,f,fp,MAX_IT):
    cnt = 0
    TOL = 1e-10
    z = z0
    condition = fp(z) != 0
    a = z[condition]
    for i in range(MAX_IT):
        dz = f(a)/fp(a)
        adz = np.absolute(dz)
        if np.all(adz < TOL) :
            return a
        cnt += 1
        a -= dz
    return False
```

It works, but it sometimes doesn't return any roots in my domain. If i restrict my min and max values to `(-2,2)` it will return +/- `pi`, which is outside my domain. But if I go up to `(-10,10)`, I will get +/- `3*pi`, and nothing else. What is the issue with my function? I've already removed all discontinuities, so that's not the problem. Why isn't `newton` returning all roots that the complex numbers in my domain can converge to?

Edit: To add clarity, I am using `meshgrid` to generate an array of initial values that are then passed to `newton`. However, I am realizing that even when running this on polynomials, I don't get all the roots. This is a problem, because Newton's method should converge on all roots (within tolerance) for polynomials given a wide enough domain. What is going on, and can I modify it to return all roots?

Comment: When you debug it, what is the *first* line that misbehaves?

Comment: Newton's method is guaranteed to converge if `f''` does not change the sign. But for `sin`, it changes at 0. And on the range [-10, 10] it changes multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

```
def newton(z0, f, fp, MAX_IT, TOL=1e-10):
    z = z0
    roots = []
    
    for _ in range(MAX_IT):
        dz = f(z) / fp(z)
        z -= dz
        
        if np.all(np.absolute(dz) < TOL):
            roots.append(z)
            # Uncomment the line below if you want to find multiple roots
            # z = z0 + 0.01  # Update the initial guess for finding another root
        
    return roots
```

This is the modified version of your code. Hope this works.

With these modifications, you should be able to use the newton function to find multiple roots within your specified domain. Remember to provide appropriate initial guesses (z0) and ensure that the functions f and fp are correctly defined for your specific problem.